# Corona SDK Game Restart

Tags: lua, composer-php, coronasdk, restart

My updated code for my game.lua file.

```
local composer=require("composer")

local physics=require("physics")
local widget=require("widget")

local scene=composer.newScene()

physics.setDrawMode("normal")
--erased system activate check later
system.activate("multitouch")

--CHECK THIS _H AND _W
_H=display.contentHeight
_W=display.contentWidth

physics.start()
 physics.setGravity(0,-5)

 trumps=0

 numTrumps=100

 startTime=20

 totalTime=20

 timeLeft=true

 playerReady=false

Random=math.random



local function Restart(event)
    if "began"==event.phase then 

if(timeLeft~=false) then
    timer.cancel(gameTimer)

    end

end
        if "moved"==event.phase then

end
            if "ended"==event.phase then
            composer.gotoScene("restarttest")
end
        end





local function gameOver(condition)
    if (condition=="winner") then
        screenText.text="Adios Trump!"

        elseif (condition=="notbad") then
            screenText.text="Barely stopped Trump"

            elseif (condition=="loser") then
                screenText.text="Ready for That Wall!"
            end
end




local function removeTrumps(obj)
    obj:removeSelf()

    trumps=trumps-1

    if (timeLeft~=false) then 
        if(trumps==0) then
            timer.cancel(gameTimer)
            gameOver("winner")

        elseif(trumps<=40) then

            gameOver("notbad")
        elseif(trumps>=31) then

            gameOver("loser")
        end

    end
end


local function countDown(event)
    if (startTime==totalTime) then
        playerReady=true
        screenText.text="Hurry!"

    end
    startTime=startTime-1
    timeText.text="Time: "..startTime

    if (startTime==0) then
        timeLeft=false
    end

end
--[[local function spawn(params)
    local myTrump=display.newImage(params.image, 25, 25)
    myTrump.myTrumpTable=params.myTrumpTable
    myTrump.index=#myTrump.myTrumpTable+1
    myTrump.myName="Donald: ".. myTrump.index

    if params.hasBody then
      myTrump.density=.1
      myTrump.friction=0
      myTrump.bounce=.9
      myTrump.radius=9
      myTrump.bodyType="dynamic"

      physics.addBody(myTrump,"dynamic",{density=myTrump.density, friction=myTrump.friction, bounce=myTrump.bounce,radius=myTrump.radius})
    end
    myTrump.myTrumpTable[myTrump.index]=myTrump
    return myTrump
end

local spawnTable={}

for i=1, 100 do
    local spawns=spawn(
    {
image="tp.png",
myTrumpTable=spawnTable,
hasBody=true,
bounce=.9,
radius=9,
density=.1,
bodyType="dynamic",
}
)
end
--]]
local function startGame()
    myTrump=display.newImageRect("tp.png",25,25)
     myTrump.x=Random(50,_W-50)
     myTrump.y=(_H+10)
     physics.addBody(myTrump,"dynamic",{density=.1,friction=0,bounce=.9,radius=9})


   function myTrump:touch(event)

    if(timeLeft~=false) then

        if (playerReady==true) then
            if(event.phase=="ended") then
            removeTrumps(self)
        end

    end
end
end
        myTrump:addEventListener("touch",myTrump)

trumps=trumps+1

if(trumps==numTrumps) then
    gameTimer=timer.performWithDelay(1000,countDown,totalTime)
else

    playerReady=false
end

end


  local gameTimer=timer.performWithDelay(20,startGame,numTrumps)


function scene:create(event)

    local screenGroup=display.newGroup()


  background=display.newImage(screenGroup,"tflag.png")

  but1=widget.newButton{screenGroup,label="Restart",onEvent=Restart}
but1.x=_W/2+150
but1.y=_H-10

 screenText=display.newText(screenGroup,"...Waiting for Trump...",0,0,native.systemFont,16*2)
screenText.xScale=.5
screenText.yScale=.5
screenText.anchorX=(0)
screenText.anchorY=(0)
screenText.x=_W/2-210
screenText.y=_H-20


  timeText=display.newText(screenGroup,"Time:"..startTime,0,0,native.systemFont,16*2)
timeText.xScale=.5
timeText.yScale=.5
timeText.anchorY=0
timeText.anchorX=0
timeText.x=_W/2
timeText.y=_H-20

 leftWall=display.newRect(screenGroup,483,50,1,1000)
   leftWall:setFillColor(0,0,200)

  rightWall=display.newRect(screenGroup,0,0,1,1000)
   rightWall:setFillColor(0,0,200)

  ceiling=display.newRect(screenGroup,150,0,1000,1)
  ceiling:setFillColor(0,0,200)

physics.addBody(leftWall,"static",{bounce=.1})
physics.addBody(rightWall,"static",{bounce=.1})
physics.addBody(ceiling,"static",{bounce=.1})

end

function scene:show(event)
    local screenGroup=display.newGroup()
if event.phase=="will" then


  end
 if event.phase=="did" then 

 end 

end


function scene:hide(event)
    local screenGroup=display.newGroup()
    if event.phase=="will" then
    end
    if event.phase=="did" then
Runtime:removeEventListener("touch",myTrump)

end
end

function scene:destroy(event)
    if event.phase=="will" then
physics.removeBody(leftWall)
physics.removeBody(rightWall)
physics.removeBody(ceiling)
physics.removeBody(myTrump)
display.remove(myTrump)
display.remove(timeText)
display.remove(screenText)
display.remove(but1)
display.remove(background)
display.remove(screenGroup)


end
if event.phase=="did" then
end

    end


scene:addEventListener("create",scene)
scene:addEventListener("show",scene)
scene:addEventListener("hide",scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroy",scene)

return scene
```

Now this is my code for my restart file

```
  local composer=require("composer")
local scene=composer.newScene()


--background
function scene:create(event)


--background=display.newImage(screenGroup,"tflag.png")


end

function start(event)
    if event.phase=="began" then
        --composer.removeScene("game1")

end
  if event.phase=="ended" then
  --composer.gotoScene("game1")

end
end

function scene:show(event)

--background:addEventListener("touch",start)
if event.phase=="will" then
composer.removeScene("game1")


 else if event.phase=="did" then

composer.gotoScene("game1")
end
end
end

function scene:hide(event)
    if event.phase=="will" then 
end
if event.phase=="did" then 
    --background:removeEventListener("touch",start)

end
    end

function scene:destroy(event)


end


scene:addEventListener("create",scene)
scene:addEventListener("show",scene)
scene:addEventListener("hide",scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroy",scene)



return scene
```

MY only problem is that when i restart the images of the trumps are no longer on the screen but are still there but just invisible you can say. So when the new images come in after restarting the game they cant go to the top of the screen like they're supposed to because they are being stopped by the invisible "trumps" from the previous game.

My game is based off this game, but there are no balloons instead there are pictures of Donald Trump.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/22064/how-to-make-a-simple-game-with-corona

Comment: Thank you Brett but I still have a problem. The trumps don't go to the top now but the timers work as intended. Thank you for that! My second problem is that the restart button only works once. I changed the physics.start() line to the beginning and i set the gravity at beginning of code too.

Comment: Do the trumps move upward at all or just stopping at a point? In addition, why use a completely different scene to restart if you aren't displaying anything new? Can't you just make your restart button reset the trumps and timers directly?

Comment: The reset issue may be because you are not destroying that scene. You are creating it again but not removing the current. composer:gotoScene() will not recall the scene:create() method unless it was destroyed.

Comment: They are stopping at a point and I made another restart scene because I will add objects to that later. And once the game restarts the trumps go up until a little below the top and they don't go up anymore. Also how should I go about destroying the game scene because I destroyed all the objects I'm pretty sure. Can you tell me how I should edit my code? I thought I did remove the current scene in the destroy scene.

Comment: My thing works now almost. My only problem is that when I restart the scene my trumps don't go to the top of the screen, it's like the ceiling has come down. I think it is due to the _H and _W can you check that out please?

Comment: It is hard for me to imagine what it looks like and how it is acting. However, I can offer some tips for you to debug it. Try coloring the ceiling's rectangle in order to see where it is being placed. This way you can tell if it moves for some reason. I've had issues where y-position 0 is not at the top. I believe the position is somehow relative. Secondly, you can try to remove the physics "static" of the ceiling and test to see if the Trumps continue to go upward. This will help rule if it is the ceiling or not.

Comment: It is the ceiling, when i removed the static part the trumps continued upward and off the screen after i restarted and before i restarted.

Comment: How should i fix this ceiling?

Comment: What do you mean by the position is relative

Comment: Display groups can cause the display objects to be positioned relative to the other display objects. You can see that here https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/group.html I am unsure why it only does it during your restart, though. Are you positive that your display objects are completely removed?

Comment: Ok so I have been checking stuff out and everything is fine with my app except the ceiling of course but I colored the ceiling and found out that it isn't the ceiling. The trumps (images of trump) just go midway up the screen and stop like there is an invisible barrier a bit under where the ceiling is at?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is causing it to stop is that there are trumps behind the background lingering from the previous scene (because it is AFTER you restart, right?). You can reach more corona developers by posting your issues on corona's forums.

Comment: So I messed around with the code and yes your hunch is correct it is like the trumps from the previous game before restarting are invisible but still there. How should I solve this? Can you check my code that I already posted or should I update my code to what I have now?

Comment: This usually means that your display objects were not destroyed properly. It seems that you are destroying "MyTrump", which is currently only set to 1 of them, not all of them. So, many of them are still lingering behind the background. When creating a trump, add it to a list, and at the end of the scene remove that list. It will remove them all. It is also good practice to remove the physics body and then remove the display body. If you have any issues with creating/removing the list, you should create a new question.

Comment: The amount of trumps left are the ones I don't make disappear in previous round. If you touch a trump it disappears, however many trumps I don't make disappear linger for the next round.

Comment: Should I create a spawn table then?

Comment: Those trumps are likely behind your background because you re-create it. Display images are placed on top of others if placed later. You can try using to object:toFront() on the Trumps or use object:toBack() on the background. A spawn table would make it more organized, but I don't think it will solve your display issues.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry for annoying you btw, but thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I have a line in my code that goes gameTimer=performWithDelay(20, startGame,numTrumps)

Comment: This makes the game start with 20 seconds call the startGame function and generate 100 trumps with the image of myTrump since numTrumps is a global variable that =100. Could I manipulate that on restart and make those trips disappear because I tried but it didn't work but there could be a way so I'm asking.

Comment: This makes the game start with 20 seconds call the startGame function and generate 100 trumps with the image of myTrump since numTrumps is a global variable that =100. Could I manipulate that on restart and make those trips disappear because I tried but it didn't work but there could be a way so I'm asking..But I was thinking making another function that removes one myTrump one by one without touching them and then I can make that function in the timer and make the iterations the amount of trumps left by making numtrumps ..numTrumps=numTrumps-trumps. How should I approach that?

Comment: My above comment is an add one to the one before it there was a weird glitch that happened.

Comment: You should probably make a new question being that we are now getting off of the topic for this one. In addition, others may see your newer questions and could help.

Comment: Alright I did. But I made a function to remove ONE mytrump but I repeated that 70 times through using a gameTimer that will be activated upon restarting the game yet only one myTrump is removed. So I need help for that because the only other thing that could possible be done is to make 100 different variables for the same image that myTrump uses so I could make myTRUMP1, myTrump2...... But that could lag my game.

Answer (score 2):

I am also quite new to using composer, but when you call removeScene("game1"), this calls the scene:destroy function. In this function, you need to remove the display objects that were created. Because you are not doing this, it is likely that the objects still exist behind your newly created ones, which are causing odd physics issues. Let me know if this helps at all.